# Redirect nginx to another domain with authorization header

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect request from nginx to another domain, below is a working solution for redirect request but it doesn't redirect `Authorization` header from original request, is it possible to redirect to another domain with all request headers from original request?

```
location /test {
    return 301 https://test.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You can proxy_pass the request

Comment: @miknik thanks, that worked, can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `return` directive, which will issue a redirect to the client browser you can use the `proxy_pass` directive instead which will proxy the original client request to the remote server with the request headers intact.